# how to import public key in windows IIS

Tags: iis, rsa, public-key

in unix we put public key under /.ssh/authorized_keys 
but in case of windows, where should I put or import public key?

Comment: What kind of public key? Why is it related to IIS?

Comment: I want to handle password-less sftp. my ftp server is windows server. so whenever, client wants to connnect to ftp server he will use his private key to login. but before that I should put/ import his public key. so, I am not sure how and where to import that public key.

Comment: IIS does support FTPS but not SFTP.

Comment: Thank you Lex. Could you please let me know the solution for passworldess sftp on windows ftp ? Is there any free application that we can use?

Comment: There is none from Microsoft yet. You will have to find a third party solution.